# Windows XP mode in Win 7 - Do I need to install an antivirus?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, virtualization, antivirus, virtual-pc

I already run NAV 2011 in my Windows 7 machine. Do I need to install it on the virtual XP machine too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep you will need to install it on your virtual machine as you won't get protection from the windows 7 A/V instance.

Hope this helps

Comment: FWIW if you download the win 8 release preview, it comes with msft forefront security integrated into the iso, thus alleviating the need of installing an additional anti-virus program.

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/iso/